# Sync Outlook 2016 Calendar to outlook.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Windows10 Office365 Outlook2016   /   outlook.com
emails sync; calendars do not; contacts sync but without categories.
It is possible to sync calendars without a third party app?
Thanks
Frank

Comment: Please try setting up outlook as shown in link: http://webmakers.co.nz/outlook-2013-exchange-configuration-setup-office-365/  This Worked for me and emails, Calendars and Contacts syncs on Outlook 2016, OWA and Mobile.

Comment: The directions above are actually wrong. Step 6 should be for Outlook.com (aka Hotmail.com). Follow these instructions instead: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/olc-hotmail/sync-calendar-contacts-using-outlook-com/ -- Outlook.com is supposed to migrated over to Exchange in the middle of this year, but I don't think they are quite done yet.

Comment: @Jatlin, the link is for setting up a new account. I already have my account setup. I also refers to Exchange Server which I don't have access to. I'm reluctant to edit my current settings without being sure I wont mess anything up. Can you confirm that it's okay to edit as per the "new" instructions.